# I get x and y labels and the incremental data but no graph line. Using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

```
# imports the necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# loads the unemployment dataset`enter code here`
unemployment = pd.read_csv(r'c:\unemployment.csv')

# title
plt.title('U.S. unemployment rate', fontsize = 20)

# x and y axis labels`enter code here`
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('% of total labor force')

# plot
plt.plot(unemployment["Year"], unemployment["Value"])

# saves the image
plt.savefig("unemployment.png")

# shows the image
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you see anything different in the saved .png file?  It might be helpful if you trim down the dataset and post some of the values into the code for inspection...

Comment: This doesn't make sense, try to attach the resulting plot to this post and describe what's missing.